# Create a Golang struct from an XSD

Tags: xml, go, xsd

I want to create a Golang struct from an XSD (Structure XSD).

I've read the post [generate Go structs from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734450/generate-go-structs-from-xsd) which recommend using go-xsd,  but I have downloaded go-xsd and installed xsd-makepkg and I cannot generate my struct.

What I am doing?

xsd-makepkg -basepath="/Users/XSD_Access/" -goinst=false

-xsd-makepkg: it is the binary create from apart [go-xsd-pkg](http://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd-pkg)
 -basepath: Contains the route where I have Structure XSD that I want to transform to struct.
 -goinst : I have not installed go-buildrun and I think it is not neccesary , for that reason is ser false

What is the result of the command?

A folder($GOPATH/usr/Users/XSD_Access/) that contains other folders with all followers XML wrappers

- docbook.org
- docs.oasis-open.org
- kbcafe.com
- khronos.org
- schemas.opengis.net
- thearchitect.co.uk
- Users
- www.w3.org

Structure XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="Request" type="Request"/>
   <xs:complexType name="Request">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation xml:lang="sp"><![CDATA[
        Comment xxxxx
     ]]></xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="idOne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation xml:lang="sp"><![CDATA[Comment xxxxx
     ]]></xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="idTwo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation xml:lang="sp"><![CDATA[Comment xxxxxx
     ]]></xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what step I missed that it does not let me create a struct from my Structure XSD?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

xsd-makepkg expects to download the xsd files from a network server of some sort.

I was confused by this at first as well, since the documentation mentioned building from local files, but that only works if the files specified are already downloaded.

`-basepath=""`  determines where these files will be downloaded to, and where the generated .go files will be put

what you're looking for is the `-uri=""` argument. `-uri=""` determines *which* files are to be downloaded and processed. The argument takes a whitespace separated list of uris, and `http://` is optional.

A quick and dirty way to make it work with a local file is to serve the file from a local Apache instance, then point the program to localhost. That is of course assuming that you happen to have a web server running.

for example:

```
mv *.xsd /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
for xsd in *; do xsd-makepkg -uri="127.0.0.1/$xsd"; done
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this command line option:

**-local=true**  :Local copy -- only downloads if file does not exist locally

The below statement worked with mydomain.xsd in the xsd-schema folder.

xsd-makepkg -local=true -uri="mydomain.xsd" -basepath="github.com/my_name/xsd-schema"

reference: https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd#command-line-flags-for-go-xsdxsd-makepkg-tool